# Can a secondary audio wire harness be spliced into a factory head unit harness?

Tags: nissan, audio, speakers, titan, head-unit

Working on a Titan I do not want to get rid of the factory 6 disc changer but I would like to run an aftermarket amp and subs.  When I integrate custom features I like to make sure I can fallback to stock for whatever reason or if I wanted to sell the truck.

I've ran a [line-output convertor](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/metra-two-channel-line-output-converter/1265702.p?skuId=1265702) before and I've seen we have a similar question: "[Amp Install Question. Splice in pre or post factory amp?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/amp-install-question-splice-in-pre-or-post-factory-amp)".  I was wondering if I buy an aftermarket wire harness and cut a wire harness from another Titan and soldiered all the connections into the convertor with a wire length not exceeding 6" would I run into electrical issues since the ohm and amps would slightly change?

Another solution I've contemplated was to push the pins out for the rear speakers and soldier the convertor directly to the pins and push them back into the plug that goes into the head unit.  Would there be another clean option?

Answer (score 2):

You want a line-out converter. You need rca pre-amp outputs, but your factory radio doesn't have them. You can tap into the speaker connection at the speaker closest to where you will install the amp to put in your line-out converter. This will provide you with an rca source for your amp. Then wire your amp and subs as usual. There's no reason to mess around in the dash for this.

Comment: Yes, I am aware I need a line-out converter as stated in the question.  I also recall the last one I ran needed two wire sets, mostly tied into the rear to work.  So your solution to add it to one speaker I do not think will work as I would need to also tie it into another set.  Also, I've heard, and as stated in the referenced Q&A the best signal is obtained at the head unit pre-amp.